# Laravel "npm run watch" command shoing error.... what to do

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

I have seen some stackoverflow post about this but any of them is not working for me . please find a solution for this problem

when I run -"npm run watch" on my windows 10 it shows this and doesn't work. my main goal is to install mix on my laravel. I am working on .vue in laravel.

> watch
> mix watch

```
[webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'resolve'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\devil\tamimwasif\node_modules\rechoir\lib\register.js
- C:\Users\devil\tamimwasif\node_modules\rechoir\index.js
- C:\Users\devil\tamimwasif\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\utils\index.js
- C:\Users\devil\tamimwasif\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js
- C:\Users\devil\tamimwasif\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\bootstrap.js
- C:\Users\devil\tamimwasif\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js
- C:\Users\devil\tamimwasif\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (C:\Users\devil\tamimwasif\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\devil\tamimwasif\node_modules\rechoir\lib\register.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\devil\tamimwasif\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\devil\\tamimwasif\\node_modules\\rechoir\\lib\\register.js',
    'C:\\Users\\devil\\tamimwasif\\node_modules\\rechoir\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\devil\\tamimwasif\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\lib\\utils\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\devil\\tamimwasif\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\lib\\webpack-cli.js',
    'C:\\Users\\devil\\tamimwasif\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\lib\\bootstrap.js',
    'C:\\Users\\devil\\tamimwasif\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\bin\\cli.js',
    'C:\\Users\\devil\\tamimwasif\\node_modules\\webpack\\bin\\webpack.js'
  ]
}
```

Comment: You have to install auth first

Comment: Did you run ```npm install``` command?

Comment: Update your node version and try again.

Comment: how to install auth please tell

Comment: after updating the nodejs and running nmp install still i am facing the same error.......................... please helppppppppppppp